# What do you call the fear of forgetting (specifically something one cherishes a lot)?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that describes the fear of forgetting? In my case I'm in search of a word meaning fearing to forget a beautiful memory.

Comment: It ought logically to be _lethophobia_, but that doesn’t really appear to be in any kind of real use, nor to be included in dictionaries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [Mnemophobia](http://raychairil.blogspot.com/2013/01/mnemophobia.html)

is literally the fear *of* memories, usually bad ones, but is also used for fear of their loss. It is directly from the analogous Greek roots for 'memory' and 'fear of'.